# How can i add a default culture between an http request and http response if the request contains an unsupported culture?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, localization, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a template asp.net core mvc project and i'd like to set up localization.

What i realized is that if i set up my default cultureinfo then it will always be picked if it's inside the accept-language header regardless of it's position or precedence (q-factor weighting).

So i came up with the idea to not set a default cultureinfo at all so it can depend on the request's header. There's only 1 problem with it. I'm not sure what will happen if the accept-header contains a culture that is not supported by my application.

Is there any way to set up some kind of middleware between a request and response so i can set the default culture if the request contains an unsupported culture?

Here's my relevant part of the code inside startup.cs:

```
IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("de"),
    new CultureInfo("en"),
    new CultureInfo("fr")
};

var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Core 3.1 has come with `Globalization and Localization Middleware` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1). And this is built-in middleware for you [Accept-Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-accept-language-http-header).

Therefore, if there are no `Accept-Language`, the default `Culture` will be `Server Culture`. If you want to set `default` that you don't sure about `Server Culture`, you can write a custom middleware [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-a-custom-provider) to force your default `Culture`